# How to prevent widget from shrinking after setting a layout to its parent?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a QGroupBox and a QTabWidget side by side inside centralwidget and want the QGroupBox to have a fixed width and expanding height and the QTabWidget to have both expanding width and height.

The problem arises when I set a horizontal layout to the centralwidget. Everything expands fine but my QGroupBox shrinks in width.

How do I prevent this shrinking from happening while maintaining the expandability of the widgets?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Example of this with a minimal .ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>640</width>
    <height>313</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="title">
       <string>GroupBox</string>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>140</y>
         <width>231</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>This text is supposed to be visible in its entirety.</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 1</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
       <attribute name="title">
        <string>Tab 2</string>
       </attribute>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, added a ui file that reproduces it

Answer (score 0):

Adding a widget to a parent isn't enough to make that parent resize itself enough so that the child becomes completely visible. A layout manager not only ensures that all widgets are correctly resized, but also that the widget on which the layout is set knows if they require more (or less) space than it actually provides.

Right now, you don't have any layout set for the left groupbox, so each one of the groupbox children is "free" and can be theoretically moved and resized no matter what. At the same time, the groupbox could be resized if necessary, as it doesn't have any constraints: in the main layout of the main window you have also a QTabWidget (which is a widget that automatically tries to expand to the maximum available space), and since the groupbox doesn't have any constraints, the result is that the tab widget will occupy most of the width, except for the minimum required by the groupbox (its frame and its title).

To solve your problem, set a layout for the groupbox and it will be automatically resized in order to correctly show its contents: ensure that *at least* one widget exists in the groupbox, right click on an empty area of the box and select one of the layout managers in the "Lay out" submenu.